# Prevent window hiding, JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I have some problem in my application start. Running Linux - it's fine. But when i launch it under Windows - application hiding immediately to task bar. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code of main:

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MainLayout.fxml"));
        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
        MainController controller = fxmlLoader.getController();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        controller.setStage(primaryStage);
        controller.startNetworking(9000);
        primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(AudioGuideManager.class.getResource("/resources/icon.png").toString()));
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.DECORATED);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

Comment: The source seems fine to me. Are you using [`stage.setIconified()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setIconified%28boolean%29) somewhere?

Comment: What is your `controller` doing?